# Tkinter Python: Moving multiple widgets at once

Tags: python, tkinter

If I have multiple widgets within a Frame, is there a way to shift all widget positions at once with a command? I am using the .place manager. Thanks!

Comment: you can move `Frame` with all elements at once - or you have to move every element separatelly. Remove `Frame` (or every element) with `place_forget()` and put again with `place()`.

Comment: I recommend you explaining a bit more about what you're trying to accomplish. If you feel the need to move a bunch of widgets as a group, there's probably a better solution than using `place`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define variables `ref_y` and `ref_y` and just add them to my current `x` and `y` value as in:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

ref_x = 40
ref_y = 56

btn = tk.Button(root, text="Button")
lbl = tk.Label(root, text="Label")

btn.place(x=ref_x + 45, y=ref_y + 13)
lbl.place(x=ref_x + 13, y=ref_y + 44)

root.mainloop()
```

In the above example `btn` and `lbl` will be placed with referece to `ref_x` and `ref_y`. Which means if you want to place the widgets elsewhere keeping their relative position to each other, you just need to modify `ref_x` and `ref_y` values.

Answer (score 0):

If you have all in `Frame` then you can move `Frame` and it will move with all elements inside.

Use `place_forget()` to remove it from window, and use `place()` again to put in new position.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

# --- funtions ---

def move():
    # hide frame
    f.place_forget()

    # random positiom
    new_x = random.randint(0, 100)
    new_y = random.randint(0, 150)

    # show in new place
    f.place(x=new_x, y=new_y)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

f = tk.Frame(root)
f.place(x=0, y=0)

tk.Label(f, text='HELLO!').pack()
tk.Button(f, text='Move it', command=move).pack()

root.mainloop()
```